# Do we need a retag tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

On Anime SE, there is a *retag* tag. You use it when you are choosing a new anime with no existing tags. This way, the members with more points can create a tag for that anime.

Do we need something similar here?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a fan.  150 rep isn't all that hard to obtain, which is what you need to create new tags.  In the mean time, new users can just state what tag/s they need.  Often times brand new users don't quite understand the tag system, so it's better for the site if they can't create tags willy nilly.

The standard way would be to flag, leave a comment, or even include the tag in the question itself, and then anyone with the appropriate privileges can fix things up if appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds interesting. While it will often happen automatically, it might be quite convenient to check for all `retag`-tagged questions occasionally. But then again we would need to make this policy clear to every new user. Because more often than not an appropriate tag already exists and the user just forgets to tag it this way or isn't aware of the title-tag policy and in this case it isn't more likely that they use the `retag` tag either. And those that are aware of this policy sometimes post an appropriate tagging request in a comment anyway.

So while it might be a nice idea, I'm not sure it will really buy much, yet it might be worth a try as it surely doesn't hurt anybody either. As long as it can be integrated into the SE-architecture, since this tag will normally have no questions associated with it and thus might dissolve if not used for a longer period.

Comment: It can't really be 'integrated' per-se, but interested users can add it to their "favourite tags" list and get a visual of something that is on the front page that needs re-tagging.